# Google Hacked IP Address - Subpoena to Google

Tags: ip, gmail

I suspected somebody hacked into my email account and sent messages from it, so I served Google with a subpoena to produce the IP addresses of the computer that sent the hacked emails.

Google produced the following:

```
X-Originating-IP: 2001:e68:5413:720c:885d:5a28:4583:a4ac

X-Originating-IP: 2001:e68:5413:720c:d45b:e46:2578:6ec9

X-Originating-IP: 2001:e68:5413:720c:3c4c:924d:f3bb:ffa1
```

Anyone know how to interpret this????

Comment: They are IPV6 addresses. 2001:e68:5413:720c:885d:5a28:4583:a4ac MY Malaysia is an example of where it came from. Couldve been a server they bounced off of though

Comment: Note to close voters: just because the information came from GMail doesn't mean that interpreting the e-mail headers and IP addresses is off-topic. I'm voting Leave Open.

Comment: How did you got the IPs? Where did you served this to Google? served what? If you are saying that you sent "some kind of legal letter/standard-common letter-sent-to-Google in these situations" to Google and they sent these IPs; then it is that "google reveled/said" not "produced" - the word _produced_ seemed like you sent google some Email-headers and then magically "found/made" a IP address.

Comment: Can anyone produce a fully comprehensive list of info of these IPs? like not limiting to geography? I think lot of people will know these tools: probably from these digital world or github...

Answer (score 9):

There are [IPv6 IP adresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv6_addresses). The difference between familiar to you IPv4 adresses is that IPV6 one are 128 bits long.

All of them are located in Malysia so if you're not located there then it's likely you've been hacked.

Comment: Hacked, you mean guessed their easy password.